# receiving error response from android with JSON/PHP

Tags: php, android, json, phpmyadmin, jsonresult

I'm coding my android app which shares DB tables with PHP forum in my local server. My app users needs to register before he/she can start using the app and one of the functions in my app is to allow those registered users to send/view posts and comments to/of the forum all are done from the Android app interface not by calling the whole forum into my phone but I used JSON in this task with different responses. Unfortunately every time I register I receive an error response, but I could not figure out why

this is the error response that I got

```
03-14 16:14:52.361: E/JSON(400): {"tag":"register","success":0,"error":1,"error_msg":"Error occured in Registartion"}
```

and this is my index.php

```
<?php

   /**
 * File to handle all API requests
 * Accepts GET and POST
*
* Each request will be identified by TAG
 * Response will be JSON data

/**
* check for POST request
 */
if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
// get tag
$tag = $_POST['tag'];

// include db handler
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// response Array
$response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 0, "error" => 0);

// check for tag type
if ($tag == 'login') {
    // Request type is check Login
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // check for user
    $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);
    if ($user != false) {
        // user found
        // echo json with success = 1
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["id"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["name"] = $user["username"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
        $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user not found
        // echo json with error = 1
        $response["error"] = 1;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else if ($tag == 'register') {
    // Request type is Register new user
    $name = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // check if user is already existed
    if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
        // user is already existed - error response
        $response["error"] = 2;
        $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed";
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // store user
        $user = $db->storeUser($name,  $password, $email);
        if ($user) {
            // user stored successfully
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["id"] = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["username"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
            $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user failed to store
            $response["error"] = 1;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Registartion";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid Request";
}
  } else {
echo "Access Denied";
  }
  ?>
```

this is my STOREUSERFUNCTION

```
 public function storeUser($name, $password, $email) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user(unique_id, username, password, salt, email,  created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name',  '$encrypted_password', '$salt', '$email',  NOW())");
    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        // get user details
        $id = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = $id");
        // return user details
        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I really could not figure out what is wrong here as earlier I could run it fine but now I modify this code to store the details in user table of the forum so I can deal with one table for user data
I feel quite comfortable with the new code here-I mean I guess it's not the cause of the error response- but I doubt with table but any way I'm not sure where is the mistake that triggers the error response

Comment: Instead of setting the `error_msg` to that generic message, why don't you return the error message of your database client (something like `$db->mysql_error()`

Comment: Can you confirm that user didn't get saved to the database?  I think that may be your issue. $user = $db->storeUser($name,  $password, $email);  Check the values you are sending.

Comment: @323go but then I got error saying call to undefined method

Comment: @karmafunk yes my user table is empty it didn't get my values....what do you mean by check values I'm sending do you mean their data type or what...plz cop with me I still in my beginning

Comment: Do what @323go suggested and see what the mysql error is.  This will give us an indication of the problem. $response["error_msg"] = $db->mysql_error(); instead of $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Registartion";  If not obvious then check the values you are sending.

Comment: Have you initialised the databse?  Also, what framework are you using?

Comment: @captinmemo - I said "something *like* `$db->mysql_error()`" -- I don't recognize the db you're using, so you'll need determine the correct function to retrieve the last error.

Comment: Can we see the storeUser function?

Comment: I got this error now                                               03-15 15:13:59.820: E/JSON(364): <br />
03-15 15:13:59.820: E/JSON(364): <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method DB_Functions::mysql_error() in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\android_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>77</b><br />
03-15 15:13:59.820: E/JSON Parser(364): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: @karmafunk I have edited the question and included the store user function you may check it

Comment: OK, this is because your database class doesn't have the mysql_error function so remove that.  Can we see your table structure?

Comment: @karmafunk Table structure for table `user`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `unique_id` varchar(23) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `avatar` text,
  `signup_date` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  FULLTEXT KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: So debugging this is difficult as it is being called from an android app. Here is what to do. You can call the index.php directly from the browser. domain.com/url_structure/index.php?tag=register&username=xxx&password=xxx&email=xxx Replace xxx with your vals. Be sure to change all the $_POST vars to $_GET.  Does this work?  If not then edit the DB_functions.php and echo mysql_error() after the query has executed as see what it returns.

Comment: @karmafunk I test it in my browser and from my app. and it's OK.but I still can't perform login from the browser I got access denied and from my app I got incorrect email or password response

Answer (score 0):

OK guys now I fixed it it's fine no issues 
it was the function in my android side that makes the login request, it's parameters are not set in order that matches the order of the function in my php file.
thanks a lot dude 
special thanks goes to karmafunk you did help me a lot which you all the best

hope my question would help others with same matter.